# How to keep disagreements healthy as a leader?

Tags: team, meetings

In my meetings, disagreements tend to be quite unhealthy from my point of view. They don't become toxic or offensive at all, but you can just feel the environment charging up a bit. Therefore, I am either notified later by other members about it or am told on the spot through a text message. As a result, what are ways through which I can keep disagreements healthy? To start with myself, when discussing what we disagree on, how can I eliminate any form of tension and ensure that I continue to deliver my different point of view without charging up the meeting?

Comment: What is the nature of the disagreement? What is the source of tension?

Comment: Could you clarify your role and the nature / structure of your team?

Comment: @JoelEtherton It is often about difference in opinion. The issue is when disagreements happen in area of someone's expertise. For example, we're an event management organization. Therefore, our Events Manager is responsible for organizing events etc. At times, their way appears inefficient or lacking in some areas, so I, or other members, intervene. This is what may create the tension, since we may appear to be interrupting or intervening in their work, something which he may consider as intrusive. How can we deliver our opinions in a way that still appreciates and acknowledges their position?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere My position seldom requires me to bring forward ideas. Therefore, there is rarely any need for them to disagree with me. My concern is when it's the opposite case: them coming up with ideas which I disagree with in some areas. It's worth noting that it is not always only I who shows disagreement; other members disagree as well.

Answer (score 3):

I work in cybersecurity in the USA and have been the technical lead / team lead for my team for about 3 years. What I have found useful as a framework to keep duscussions healthy is summarized below.

**Do not take disagreement personally, as if they are targeted specifically towards you.**

As long as conflict is focused on the problem, does not stray from the topic, and are devoid of personal attacks, **conflict is healthy** for team dynamics if it means problematic actions are caught earlier, and all possible solutions are considered. Groupthink and a culture in which team members are afraid to speak up and voice their opinions often lead to suboptimal work. If someone disagrees with an idea of mine, its not an indication that I am incompetent or they dont like me **as a person or employee**

**Remain calm and defuse if conflict escalates to point of outright anger**

Sometimes people can be passionate about certain topics that are important to them. If there is opposition in these cases, it can trigger anger in those folks across the table from you. An important part of calming the temperature is to recognize that people are entitled to their opinions and group consensus may not be the end goal, even though such agreement is ideal. If personal attacks, such as name calling, happens, then let it be known that such attacks are unhelpful. As needed, you may need to separate the individuals until tempers are calm again and rational discussion is possible. Let yourself serve as a model of professionalism, self discipline and restraint.

**Be open to your team and do not be hypocritical**

From my work experience in the USA, employee autonomy and independence of thought is often valued. People appreciate managers who are transparent, approachable, and serve as a coach to team members, rather than a manager ruling with an iron fist from up above.

Therefore show that you are someone that your team members can count on for support.  Come down to their level as much as possible. Try to walk around with them and observe how they are doing. **The goal is so to minimize the chances your team sees their manager as a distant force, removed from the pains his / her team members are experiencing.**

**Enforce a level set of rules that applies to all members participating in that discussion prior to discussion taking place.**

Its very helpful for team members to know what the "rules of the game" are before hand. **It is critical that these rules apply to all equally and does not change during discussion.** You dont want any member to feel as if he / she is entitled to special deference / consideration not due others, or for the goalposts to move. In this manner, you avoid excuses such as  "I did not know those were the rules or they apply to me"

Comment: Thank you for this. I have a follow up if you don't mind. Regarding the first point, I do not take disagreements personally. Therefore, what is more important for me is that the person I disagree with does not take it personally, especially when following the guidelines you talked about. Are there any phrases I can use or behavior I can exhibit to let the other person understand that this is not a personal disagreement, but a professional one?

Comment: Following up on your comment, the issue is when disagreements happen in area of someone's expertise. For example, we're an event management organization. Therefore, our Events Manager is responsible for organizing events etc. At times, their way appears inefficient or lacking in some areas, so I, or other members, intervene. This is what may create the tension, since we may appear to be interrupting or intervening in their work, something which he may consider as intrusive. How can we deliver our opinions in a way that still appreciates and acknowledges their position?